# When both users are in chat room, messages are still marked unread

Tags: ios, xcode, chat, quickblox

I'm having some trouble with Quickblox chat. Whenever two users are both logged in and both joined in the same chat room, messages that are sent between the two users are not marked as read. When I back out of the room to the dialogs list and the dialogs are refreshed, it says that there are unread messages even though I was in the room and I was receiving the messages live.

Is there a certain call that I must make to let it be known that the received messages should be marked as read? I am developing in iOS.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something other than programming.

Comment: This is indeed a programming question

Comment: Only if you show some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User has to read message to mark it as read

```
NSString *dialogID = @"53d10eede4b02f496c21549f";
NSArray *mesagesIDs = @[@"53aabe15e4b077ddd43e7fd3", @"53aabe15e4b077ddd43e7fd7"];

[QBChat markMessagesAsRead:mesagesIDs dialogID:dialogID delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

In `iOS` you can use:

```
QBRequest.markMessagesAsRead(Set<String>?, dialogID: String, successBlock:
{
    (QBResponse) in code
})
{
    (QBResponse) in code
}
```